# Как перетащить файл в консоль

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать считывание модулей и.т.п из `.exe - .dll` файлов!

Подскажите как добиться эффекта `Drag and Drop` в консоль?

Хочу сделать так: если переместили не тот формат вывести ошибки что мол не тот формат) и продолжить работу.

Если же переместили нужный файл, работаем с ним...

Такой вариант не работает:

```
try
        {
            if (Path.GetExtension(args[0]) == ".exe" || Path.GetExtension(args[0]) == ".dll")
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Working.../");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct");
        }
        catch { }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В свежих версиях windows перетаскивание файла в консоль вызывает набор в консоли полного пути к файлу. Считать его вы можете обычным `Console.ReadLine()`. Не забудьте убрать кавычки (например, методом `.Trim('"')`).

Или же вы можете принимать файл как параметр (тот самый `args[0]`). Но в таком случае пользователь будет должен перетащить файл не в консольное окно - а на вашу программу.

В последнем случае пользователь также сможет кликнуть на файл правой кнопкой, выбрать пункт "открыть с помощью" и там выбрать вашу программу. Скорее всего, это будет более простой способ чем Dran'n'Drop

Comment: При "открыть с помощью" - в программу будет передан путь к файлу первым аргументом

Comment: @monobogdan *первый аргумент имеет индекс 0. Это особенность массивов в C-подобных языках, ясли вы не знали...*

Comment: @monobogdan а если серьезно - запустите да проверьте. В .NET в функцию Main имя самой программы не передается, в отличии от Си/C++.

Comment: аргумент 0 - путь к самому экзешнику, первый параметр уже и есть "имя файла"

Comment: @monobogdan повторяю: возьмите да проверьте!

Comment: зачем мне проверять, если я итак знаю? В winmain нулевой аргумент - путь к самому бинарнику

Comment: @monobogdan прочитайте мои комментарии еще раз.

Comment: @GooliveR не подскажу. Задавайте отдельный вопрос. А лучше сначала поищите ответ в гугле, наверняка же сто раз уже на него отвечали. А еще лучше - загляните в документацию...

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете это сделать хуком окна консоли.

Для этого вам необходимо получить HWND окна консоли:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

IntPtr cmdHandle = GetConsoleWindow();
```

Затем необходимо зарегистрировать Drag and Drop используя RegisterDragDrop

Больше информации о RegisterDragDrop:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Да я уверен что можно, только вот не знаю как, выдел пару приложений которые могли это делать)..

Comment: Ну я и как раз говорю, хуком окна консоли можно, а так скорее всего нет

Comment: А можно подробнее про хук с окном)?

Comment: Получаете HWND окна консоли(GetConsoleWindow(), это winapi функция), потом по старинке drag n drop через winapi.
См. msdn
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678405(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ответ болтается на грани хорошего комментария и плохого ответа.

Comment: Сейчас намного лучше, спасибо.

Comment: А [вот здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12662837/276994) утверждается, что RegisterDragDrop не сработает. Вы ваш код пробовали?

Comment: @VlaD, вообще то есть окно, попробуйте сделать что нибудь с GetConsoleWindow, например нарисовать текст. Вот точно так же сработает и RegisterDragDrop.

Comment: @monobogdan: Понятно. Но всё же, вы пробовали?